# How do I filter "CUSTOM" out of a string but not "CUSTOMER" in R? Grepl?

Tags: r, regex, filter, grepl

I'm trying to filter out custom items from a data frame in R using item descriptions. I want to get rid of all items with "CUSTOM" in the description, but I need to keep items with "CUSTOMER" in the description. I tried using a grepl function but to no avail. I've got 800,000+ rows of data, so something speedy would be helpful. This is just one filter out of many, so I am using dplyr and pipe operators with my other filters.

Generic code:

```
> items <- c("A", "B", "C")
> desc <- c("CUSTOM STAMP", "CUSTOMER 4X6 IN STAMP", "4X6 GENERIC STAMP")
> df <- data.frame(Items = items, Item_Desc = desc)
> df
  Items               Item_Desc
1     A            CUSTOM STAMP
2     B   CUSTOMER 4X6 IN STAMP
3     C       4X6 GENERIC STAMP
```

I've tried something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
        filter(!grepl("CUSTOM", Item_Desc, fixed = TRUE))
```

But obviously, the result is:

```
> df
  Items         Item_Desc
1     C 4X6 GENERIC STAMP
```

Whereas the desired result would be:

```
> df
  Items               Item_Desc
1     B   CUSTOMER 4X6 IN STAMP
2     C       4X6 GENERIC STAMP
```

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you just need `"\\bCUSTOM\\b"` to match `CUSTOM` as a whole word, but remove `fixed = TRUE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a regular expression here that utilizes word boundaries, `"\\bCUSTOM\\b"`.

To make it work, you need to remove `fixed=TRUE` as this argument makes the engine treat the pattern as a literal string, not a pattern.

Use

```
df <- df %>% 
        filter(!grepl("\\bCUSTOM\\b", Item_Desc))
```

See [what the pattern matches](https://regex101.com/r/vha2Rw/1). Only the items that do not match will remain in the `df` because the result of `grepl` is inverted with `!` operator.

Comment: Removing the fixed=TRUE worked wonderfully. I had previously included "\\bCUSTOM\\b" per recommendation of another question I had found, so now I know why it didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you add a space after the `CUSTOM`, it would work as long as `CUSTOM` itself is not the last word.

```
df[!grepl("CUSTOM ", df$Item_Desc),]
#  Items             Item_Desc
#2     B CUSTOMER 4X6 IN STAMP
#3     C     4X6 GENERIC STAMP
```

Or based of `strsplit`

```
df[sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Item_Desc), " "),
               function(x) all(toupper(x) != "CUSTOM")),]
#  Items             Item_Desc
#2     B CUSTOMER 4X6 IN STAMP
#3     C     4X6 GENERIC STAMP
```

Comment: This does not match if CUSTOM is at the very end. Anway you could use "CUSTOM( .*|$)".

Answer (score 2):

`grepl("CUSTOM(?!ER)", desc, perl = T)` matches CUSTOM but not CUSTOMER.